# Lucene Boolean value search with boolean query

Tags: syntax, lucene

There is a field say XYZ with value as either TRUE or FALSE. 
i am searching as following

```
+Contents:risk +XYZ:TRUE
```

is it legal to search like that? i tried but it showed me results with FALSE value too.

What was more amazing is that i searched by `+XYZ:[TRUE TO TRUE]` and it worked.

can some one tell me what exactly is my mistake?

Comment: Your query is correct. Since you have obfuscated the field name, I am not sure if the actual field name for XYZ is correct. Field names are case sensitive in Lucene. You may wish to verify that.

Comment: thank for hint; let me double check if its because of case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's perfectly fine to search like that. Did you ensure that your analyzers are correct?

Comment: I am using StandardAnalyzer. I had indexed with Lucene.NET v2.9 and searching with SOLR.NET. But before calling SOLR to search, i made a booleanQuery myself.

Comment: Following is the configuration in SOLR, Let me know if i am missing something in this;
 <fieldtype name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" luceneMatchVersion="LUCENE_29"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldtype>
 
 To add to above, i used StandardAnalyzer as : 
 analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer(new string[] { "" });